# How to control appearance of SegmentedControl within a DataElement

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I am populating a tableview with the following DataElement,

```
DataElement *ee;
ee  = [[DataElement alloc] initSegmentedControlWithLabel:@"Set Value" defaultValue:[s intValue] items:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"No", @"Yes", nil]];

[ee setTextColor;[UIColor blueColor]];
```

The last line changes the color of the label "Set Value"

I want to change the color of the SegmentedControl but can not find any method that does it.  I know how to set the tintColor and Background color of a standalone SegmentedControl, its when it is part of the DataElement that it seems to have no method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to is add some helper functions in your `DataElement` class just like `setTextColor` and set the passed arguments to the segmentedControl. Please check below:

Have a helper method like below:

```
@interface DataElement: #Your SuperClass#

-(void)setSegmentTintColor:(UIColor)color;
@end

@implementation DataElement {
    -(void)setSegmentTintColor:(UIColor)color {
        [segmentedControl setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
DataElement ee*;

//create an instance and access

[ee setSegmentTintColor: [UIColor blue]];
```

Comment: Can you share what the .h entry should be.  I'm getting an error

Comment: I updated my answer. Also, please refer to Apple documentation in declaring a method in Objective-c.

Comment: I had to include this code within the imported DataElement class.  setSegmentTintColor is not a valid method (I get errors trying to implement it) but I can use  UISegmentedControl.appearance.tintColor=[UIColor greenColor].  Run once, it sets the tintColor of all segmentedControlls in the app and even sets the background color of buttons (when you press them).  Its a very strange result.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the `@interface` in the above code is .h file declaration and `@implementation` is .m file definition. It should work if you did the same. If not pls, update the question with your latest code.